# Rename personal folder

Tags: 22.04, directory

[image]Hi everybody,

I'd like to know where and how to change the displayed name of "Home" on the desktop.
On this picture,you can see my desktop (Ubuntu 22.04 64 bits, in french, sorry...) where I like to have my personal folder (the /home/user) ; but how to do to change the displayed name "Dossier personnel" (Home) with something else ?...
Thank you for your help.

I precise that this icon (Home, or Dossier Personnel in french) is set by the extension (plugin) Dekstop Icons NG, integrated in the system, just as Trash, or external drives, etc... With this plugin (Desktop Icons NG), we can choose which icons we want to display on the desktop.
But I'd like to change the name of this icon "Home" set by this extension.

Comment: Ah thanks @Raffa I didn't spot that